# How to initialize base class property from derived class?

Tags: c#

I wrote  Following code in my mvc Application.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult StronglyTypedView()
    {
      var obj = new MvcRouting.Models.Student();
      obj.age = 24;
      obj.name = "prab";
      ViewData.Model = obj;
      return View();
    }
}
```

In above code,`ViewData` is the property of `ControllerBase` class and `Model` is the property of `ViewDataDictionary` class.Same thing i tried in following code but i am getting null values in property1,how to solve this?

```
 public interface Iface1
 {       
    int age { get; set; }
 }
 public class classA : Iface1
 {       
   public int age { get; set; }
 }
 public abstract class classB
 {       
    public classA Property1 { get; set; }
 }
 public class TEST : classB
 {
   public void test()
   {          
      Property1.age = 24;
   }
   public static void Main()
   {
     TEST obj = new TEST();
     obj.test();
     Console.Read();
   }
 }
```

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: `it's not working` is not a good explanation - do you get an error message? is it compiling? first thing i notice, you never initialize `Property1`, so it will always be `null`. That will give a `NullReference` Exceptio, when trying to set `Property1.age`...

Comment: almost 100% sure you need to do this in `test()`: `Property1 = new classA(); Property1.age=24;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting null reference exception because you need to initialize `Property1` in `classB`

```
 public interface Iface1
 {       
    int age { get; set; }
 }
 public class classA : Iface1
 {       
   public int age { get; set; }
 }
 public abstract class classB
 {       
    public classA Property1 { get; set; }
 }
 public class TEST : classB
 {
   public void test()
   {    
      if(Property1 == null)
      {
          Property1 = new classA();
      }

      Property1.age = 24;
   }
   public static void Main()
   {
     TEST obj = new TEST();
     obj.test();
     Console.Read();
   }
 }
```

Comment: @nawfal that's up to the OP and depends on a specific case. in this case it's really doesn't matters...

Comment: @nawfal you were making an argument, i gave my opinion :)

Comment: :) The "may be" part just emphasizes how typically such initializations are done in constructors. The lone upvote is mine, so no disagreement anywhere..

Comment: i have one doubt,in code there is no initialization for ViewDataDictionary.But its working

Comment: Just create one action method in controller and use ViewData.Model=some object

Comment: @PrabuParthipan ok, so here you see that the line `ViewData.Model=some object` initialize the Model object. but if they tried `ViewData.Model.prop1 = value` they would have got the same exception

Comment: no explained in my question its not throwing error,`public ActionResult StronglyTypedView()
        {
            var obj = new MvcRouting.Models.Student();
            obj.age = 24;
            obj.name = "prab";
            ViewData.Model = obj;
            return View();
        }`

Comment: @PrabuParthipan i didn't understand your comment and cannot read code like that in comment. can you edit your question please?

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead.

```
public abstract class classB
{
 public classA Property1 { get; set; }

 public classB()
 {
   Property1 = new classA();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the `Property1` before setting its property.

```
public class TEST : classB
{
   public void test()
   {    
      Property1 = new classA();
      Property1.age = 24;
   }
   public static void Main()
   {
     TEST obj = new TEST();
     obj.test();
     Console.Read();
   }
}
```